# Getting a column value in one table from another column value in different table in R

Tags: r

Below are two sample tables in R

Table1

```
ID  Name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   a
5   b
6   c
```

Table2

```
ID  Age
2   20
4   40
6   60
10  100
50  500
```

I want to create a table as below (By adding a column `Age` in `Table1` and pull the value from `Table2` based on ID column:

Output Table

```
ID  Name  Age
1   a      -
2   b     20
3   c      -
4   a     40
5   b      -
6   c     60
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: the accepted answer in the marked duplicated uses base packages.

Answer (score -1):

you could use sqldf library.

```
?sqldf

SQL select on data frames

Description

SQL select on data frames


# import the sqldf library. 
# if you get "Error in library(sqldf) : there is no package called 'sqldf' you can install it with install.packages('sqldf')
library(sqldf)

# your first df
table1 <- read.csv('/tmp/df1.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)

table2 <- read.csv('/tmp/df2.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)

table2

# express your query in terms of an SQL statement.
# in this case you want ALL the records from the first table and ALL the records from the second one which are 'matching' with the records in the first one
# In terms of SQL, this is a LEFT JOIN statement
sql <- 'select table1.id, name, age from table1 left join table2 on (table1.id = table2.id)'

# run your query
sqldf(sql)
```

and this is the results:

```
id name age
 1  1    a   -
 2  2    b  20
 3  3    c   -
 4  4    a  40
 5  5    b   -
 6  6    c  60
```

NB: if you don't have the matching records for the id 1, 3, 5 in table2, you can change your sql statement from left join to a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Feel free to ask me for further explanations, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Additionally is there a way with base package i.e. without any additional package?